# Does Wp-Ecommerce works with LinkPoint gateway?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, e-commerce, authorize.net, linkpoint

I have an online store working with osCommerce, actually works fine. But there is no integration with the store blog which is in Wordpress fortunatelly.

Now I've seen a new payment plugin for wordpress called Wp-Ecommerce , so i decided to migrate the whole store to wordpress since this can be treated like a CMS.
This plugin has really handy features like Meta Tag properties for each product in order to do SEO position for the store.
I've been reading about wp-ecommerce and searching through the web to find a chance to integrate it with LinkPoint, which is my client's store gateway. I must say this is an imperative requirement I have to do in order to migrate the whole site to Wordpress

Has anybody make this possible ? get wordpress working with LinkPoint ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it currently only supports [Authorize.Net](http://authorize.net). You may want to check out [Shopp](http://docs.shopplugin.net/Payment_Gateways). The Linkpoint plug-in is not free but it is available.